# Is there scroll component in Angular Material Design?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is there scroll component in Angular Material Design?

I have one dib block with fixed width. There are several inline block in this block. So, it has overflow property, that means is displaing horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: are you saying you want a pre-themed scrollbar that is not the one which is built into the browser?

Comment: Yes, using material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the very nature of [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel)'s like material or bootstrap, once you include the style sheet in your project if a styling is available it will be pre-styled.  Beyond that you will have to add styling yourself.  Also, it seems [many browser's don't support scroll bar styling](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scrollbar), and MVVM's try to create a fluid experience across all device types.  I suspect this is why I have never seen prestyled scroll bars in MVVM's but it also is something that is usually unique to an OS and often left alone.